# Adding domain knowledge (custom features) to NER

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, feature-selection, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm on an Ubuntu machine with Python 3.5.2 and spaCy 2.0. I'm training a blank Spanish model to recognize entities in resumes. For that I used custom word embeddings and I'm doing a large entity annotation project. I was able to segment a resume and find out which section of the resume the segment belongs to using the word embeddings and I wanna use that knowledge to augment spaCy's NER (for example, if an entity belongs to the work experience section it's more likely to be an organization than an educational institution). I was looking through the documentation and while I saw that there's a way to add custom attributes and/or calculate them using pipelines and extensions I was unable to tell whether the NER algorithm will use them as features by default or if I need to add custom code to it.

Is there any way to do this manually or is it custom behavior?

Thank you, and regards.